# Where is "What If...?" Gamora from?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel-what-if-2021

**Spoilers for the *What If...?* finale**

I know I probably just missed something in the show here, but I'm stuck.  In the finale for *What If...?* the Watcher gathers heroes from the prementioned timelines, including Captain Carter, Star Lord T'Challa, and Gamora, who's working with Tony Stark.

Again, I might've missed something, but where was Gamora from?  Is she from a timeline we've seen?  Episode 1 had Captain Carter, 2 had Star Lord T'Challa, 3 was the one Black Widow returned to at the end, 4 had Doctor Strange, 5 had the zombies that showed up, 6 had Killmonger, 7 had party Thor, and 8 had Black Widow.  So where's Gamora from?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There were supposed to be 10 episodes of *What If…?* this season, including an episode that starred this version of Gamora and Tony Stark:
https://www.polygon.com/22712630/what-if-gamora-iron-man-episode-finale-season-2

> An episode that centered on Tony Stark was supposed to premiere in this first batch of episodes, What If…? creator A.C. Bradley confirmed to Polygon. But due to COVID-19-related production issues, the episode was unable to be completed on time for release, forcing producers to bump it off to What If…? season 2 (which is good news for anyone hoping for a What If…? season 2).
>
> While “What If… The Watcher Broke His Oath?” now raises some accidental questions about Tony and Gamora’s relationship in a pocket of the multiverse, Bradley says it was worth the trouble. “Given the global tragedy of the pandemic, pushing an episode is nothing,” she wrote to Polygon. “I only hope viewers have been entertained these last 9 weeks, and enjoyed the ride as much as I did.”

Comment: I believe the premise of the missing episode was what if Tony didn’t make it back through the portal to New York?

Comment: Now we're just going to have to imagine a timeline in which they had been able to make all the episodes.

Comment: @Acccumulation Future generations may be able to simulate that if they include the episode in season 2.

Comment: Oh thank goodness, I didn't miss something important!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You didn’t miss anything in the show because Gamora’s origin story wasn't shown in Season 1. It was revealed later that Gamora hails from the timeline introduced in Season 2, Episode 4, titled “[*What If… Iron Man Crashed into the Grandmaster?*](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/What_If..._Iron_Man_Crashed_into_the_Grandmaster%3F)”

In this episode, we see how Tony Stark ended up on Sakaar after he stopped the Chitauri invasion. There, he meets Gamora from the Season 1 finale.